# mouseover and addClass jQuery example

Tags: jquery, html, css

here's a gimme for anyone that knows jQuery:

I have a navigation `<ul class="nav">` I want to change around. I'm basically looking for the `a:hover` effect, just faded in (I'm using sprites, and going from one sprite area to the next).

The code I have in my header looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav li").mouseover(function(){
    addClass('hovered');
  });
});
```

In my understanding of jQuery, this says "Once the document it ready, listen for a mouseover event on all `.nav li` elements. When you hear that, add a class "hovered" to it. So that's what I want to have happen, but right now -nothing- is happening.

Eventually I'll add in the animation and mouseOut, but I'd like to be able to get this part working as I want it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give .addClass an element to work with.

```
$(this).addClass('hovered');
```

Comment: So does $(this) become whatever was moused over? Does $(this) get set to whatever triggered the event on the "outside" of a function?

(this works, thanks)

Comment: Yes, $(this) is a reference to the object that the mouseover event is coming from, in this case, the <li> tag. Remember you have to use it in the format of a jquery selector - you can't just do this.addClass - has to be $(this).addClass

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the hover (http://api.jquery.com/hover/), and you need to target your `LI` with `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, when you do eventually do something for mouseout, you can improve readability with

```
$(".nav li").hover(function() {
  // over
}, function() {
  // and out
});
```

... or as how *I* like to do it, use the jQuery plugin [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Comment: To clarify, the second function() is the handler/callback for the hover, that fires when hover() is done (is mouse has left)?